# Optimizing Django app on a vps server

Tags: python, mysql, django, nginx, vps

Any good tutorial or method on how to optimize vps memory usage? My ram is eating up the memory. I hosted Django+Uwsgi+Nginx with MySQL as database on digitalocean 512mb vps ram. I have two sites, one of it is just hosted and no activity is going on while the second one, activity is going on but not much. And it's like a real estate site.

I run this command line code: `free -m` and it outputs:

```
total               used free shared buffers cached
Mem: 491            406  85    0      17     108
buffers/cache:      280 210
Swap:                0   0     0
```

One other thing is that, for the two sites, the uswgi is listening to different port: 127.0.0.1:8888 and 127.0.0.1:8889 Could this be part of what is eating the ram?

When I run `top` it displays this:

```
Tasks:  70 total,   1 running,  69 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    503520k total,   410436k used,    93084k free,    18920k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   111772k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
6381 meey    20   0 17320 1188  900 R  0.3  0.2   0:00.09 top
1 root      20   0 24336 2132 1256 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.70 init
2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.08 kthreadd
3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.42 ksoftirqd/0
5 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.12 kworker/u:0
6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:05.04 watchdog/0
8 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset
9 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper
10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
11 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
12 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.12 sync_supers
13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 bdi-default
14 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd
15 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd
16 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff
17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd
```

More:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
790 root      20   0  333m 129m 3992 S  0.0 26.3   2:52.59 uwsgi-core
635 mysql     20   0  870m  51m 4124 S  0.0 10.4   1:43.62 mysqld
649 www-data  20   0 63520 2436  920 S  0.0  0.5   0:30.02 nginx
779 root      20   0  124m  14m 3176 S  0.0  3.0   0:24.84 uwsgi-core
780 root      20   0  124m  14m 3176 S  0.0  3.0   0:24.30 uwsgi-core
647 www-data  20   0 63520 2592  944 S  0.0  0.5   0:21.78 nginx
648 www-data  20   0 63520 2436  920 S  0.0  0.5   0:21.72 nginx
646 www-data  20   0 63520 2568  916 S  0.0  0.5   0:20.87 nginx
602 root      20   0 84160 2148 1520 S  0.3  0.4   0:19.70 uwsgi
600 root      20   0 84160 2140 1520 S  0.0  0.4   0:19.09 uwsgi
606 root      20   0 84116  820  192 S  0.0  0.2   0:12.08 uwsgi
603 root      20   0 84116  820  196 S  0.0  0.2   0:11.99 uwsgi
7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:05.05 watchdog/0
789 root      20   0  221m  29m 3956 S  0.0  6.1   0:03.58 uwsgi-core
12 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.12 sync_supers
402 syslog    20   0  243m 1224  904 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.90 rsyslogd
624 root      20   0 19112 1000  768 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.93 cron
```

Comment: If you want to get a good answer on this you'll need to share your uwsgi configuration and your `my.cnf`. It's mostly likely that you've over specified both for the constraints of your system.

Answer (score 1):

What's eating your memory is MySQL. There is only so much performance management you can do when running a database server. They are designed to eat memory for performance's sake.

uWSGI and Nginx are very efficient. Django is not lean but memory usage is highly dependent on your app too. If you are loading a lot of modules, that would account for your memory usage.

Running `free -m` doesn't really tell us much about which processes are taking up the most memory. How about the output of `ps ax`, or looking through `top`?

Comment: I've added the top output above, kindly check it.